# How to set a selected option using ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am new to jquery and ajax. I am trying to set a selected option in my dropdown using my ajax code below:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "sample.php",
        cache: "false",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
          //data.month = 03
          $('#birth_month option[value="data.month"]').prop('selected', true);
        }
  });
```

This is my select html code:

```
<select id="birth_month" name="birth_month">
<option value="" disabled selected>Month</option>
<option value="01">January</option>
<option value="02">February</option>
<option value="03">March</option>
<option value="04">April</option>
<option value="05">May</option>
<option value="06">June</option>
<option value="07">July</option>
<option value="08">August</option>
<option value="09">September</option>
<option value="10">October</option>
<option value="11">November</option>
<option value="12">December</option>
</select>
```

And for some reason, it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for the suggestions.

Comment: You are giving data.month as string. Use + to append the value instead. Eg `$('#birth_month option[value="+data.month+"]').prop('selected', true);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have forgotten to concatenate the real value:

```
$('#birth_month option[value="'+data.month+'"]').prop('selected', true);
```

This should to the trick but you can use an easier instruction:

```
$("#birth_month").val(data.month)
```

Answer (score 2):

As `date_month` is a variable you need to create valid selector using string concatenation

Use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2), to set value

```
$('#birth_month').val(data.month);
```

Comment: How will this set the selected option?

Comment: @MisterPositive see the documentation see http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2

Comment: Learn something new every day @Satpal.  I up voted and removed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use it:

```
$('#birth_month option[value="' + data.month + '"]').prop('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
 $("#birth_month").val(data.month).attr('selected','selected');
```